# How do you divide the number of objects imported from axios?

Tags: dictionary, axios

As for importing data, Axios will bring in 100 pieces, and is there any way to put only 20 pieces out of 100 pieces separately in then or useState?
I'd like to know if there's any other way.

I would like to know if there is any other way other than using rowum >=20 as a query statement.

const [list, setList] = useState([]);

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/movielist/getMovieList_boxoffice')
        .then(res => {setList(res.data)})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },[already_released]);


 {
    list.map ((item, index) => {
          return (
               
                   <ol>
                       <li>objectnum = {index+1}</li>
                   </ol>
               

          )
      })
  }
```

`

const [list, setList] = useState([0,20]);

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/movielist/getMovieList_boxoffice')
        .then(res => {setList(res.data)})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },[already_released]);


 {
    list.map ((item, index(21)) => {
          var arr = index
          var arr1 = index(0,21)

          return (
               <div>
                   <ol>
                       <li>objectnum = {arr1+1}</li>
                   </ol>
               </div>
          )
      })
  }
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use splice to keep only the first 20 items of your data: **res.data.splice(20))**

In your case:

```
useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://localhost:8080/movielist/getMovieList_boxoffice')
        .then(res => {setList(res.data.splice(20))})
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    },[already_released]);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm planning to bring all the data, so I can print only 20 pieces from list.map.
Or...
const [list2, setlist2] useState('');
const [list3, setlist3] useState('');
Is there any way to divide 20 of them by the generation of?

Comment: Resolved with setList(res.data.splice(0,20) Thank you!!